# NAT test environments

Tags: cisco-asa

I need to create 4x test environments, each environment contains 3x servers within a 192.168.215.0/24 subnet.  Each test environment does NOT need to be aware of the other test environments.  The environments exist on an ESXi server and each have their own vSwitch.
The vSwitches are each presented through their own interface on the ESXi host to a Procurve 2810.  The Procurve is in turn connected to an ASA 5512-X.

The server at 192.168.91.1 needs to be able to connect to each host using a NAT'd address in the 192.168.93.0/24 range.  E.g. Environment 1, server 1 is 192.168.93.1, environment 2, server 1 is 192.168.93.11

I can't bring each environment into the ASA on separate interfaces as there are no more spare.

Each environment will need an internal default gateway (192.168.215.254/24) but I can't work out where to set this.  If I create separate VLANS in the Procurve they can't all have the same IP, and the same for the ASA.

I'm sure there is a really obvious answer to this, and that I am overthinking it as I've been looking at it for too long, but at the moment the answer is eluding me...

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a virtualized router in each environment that provide the local environment gateway and has the "external" IP address within the 192.168.93.0/24 network.

It is this router that would NAT traffic coming from the test environment with its 192.168.93.X IP.

Comment: Thanks JFL. As I typed the question this solution started to form. I'm currently experimenting with setting up a pfSense appliance within each environment to handle the NAT.